# Unable to run './mvnw clean install' when building docker image based on "openjdk:8-jdk-alpine" for Spring Boot app

Tags: maven, docker, spring-boot, dockerfile

I would like to build a Spring Boot app using the maven wrapper provided by spring.io.starter inside a docker container.
My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
# install bash --> commented because I just need /bin/sh which is already provided by the base image
#RUN apk add --no-cache bash
ENV APP_DIR /app
ENV APP app.jar
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}
COPY . ${APP_DIR}
# ===> HERE THE PROBLEM
RUN /bin/sh -c "./mvnw clean install"
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","chicowa-app.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

I have this error:

```
/bin/sh: ./mvnw: not found
```

After making some researches I still don't find a solution.
My docker version
`Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a` on Windows10 pro

Thanks a lot for your help.

## EDIT

A solution would be to install maven directly with a `RUN apk add --no-cache maven` but I would like to minimize as possible the image' size.

Comment: Hmm what's the value of ${APP_DIR}

Comment: `ENV APP_DIR /app` this is the directory where all files are copied to

Answer (score 6):

We were experimenting this issue only on Windows 10 and were able to solve this issue on just applying dos2unix

```
dos2unix mvnw
```

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue when build Dockerfile in Window 10. 
This because `mvnw` file contains **CRLF** (**\r\n**) at the end of line. I open it with Notepad++ and use Find `\r\n` and Replace with `\n` (with Extended (\n, \r, ...) checked). You can use dos2unix tool to convert as @Juanan said above.

After that, the build run with no problem.

Comment: Had same issue and replacing line endings worked perfected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are running the script in the exact location that the file mvnw is located, it won’t work.

If your PATH is set correct, and Maven was installed in a suitable location, simply removing the “./“ in front of the command will suffice.

```
RUN /bin/sh -c “mvnw clean install”
```

If mvnw is NOT in your PATH, you can specify the full path in your script (but recognize that Maven is likely to call other things that would want the same PATH changes).

Comment: I removed the `./` but same result. I don't want to install Maven so what do you mean by "If your PATH is set correct, and Maven was installed in a suitable location..."

Comment: If you haven’t installed Maven, then mvnw does not exist, and there is no solution to your problem, that doesn’t include installing maven.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. Take a look here about the `maven wrapper` https://www.baeldung.com/maven-wrapper

Comment: I did misunderstand, that said, I’m not sure why that page is claiming you won’t need maven installed.  The installation instructions for maven wrapper specifically use Maven.  You can’t add it to the project and get the required files downloaded, without it.

    cd your_project
    mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper
Good luck.

Comment: I did the test on my PC, I removed MAVEN_HOME from the PATH, run the `./mvnw clean install` in my project and it worked. So the author of that page is absolutely right.

Comment: Exactly.  On Your PC that had Maven installed, you set up a project with Maven Wrapper.  If you want to setup a new project, on a new computer, you have to install the maven wrapper in that project too.  The command to do that is a maven command.

Comment: If we need to have maven installed before running the wrapper so the wrapper would be absolutely useless. It does not make sense I think.

Comment: You can use maven to add the wrapper to a project, then remove maven from your machine, and then use the maven-wrapper.  It could have been explained better.

Answer (score 1):

if you have already maven configured then you may run the following:-

```
mvn clean install
```

It will build the docker image seamlessly.

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

use

```
RUN chmod +x mvnw
```

before using

```
./mvnw clean install
```

it'll make your mvnw file executable

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows git may change the line ending of the mvnw file to CRLF. If you open the file with any text editor and save it to LF it will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can also be fixed without bothered with line endings or path variables even on Windows10.

Just include Maven to your Dockerfile and run the maven commands via this:

Here is an example Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.1-openjdk-17-slim AS builder   # <-- Include Maven
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml ./
COPY src ./src

RUN mvn clean install

# Second stage: Minimal runtime environment
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy
WORKDIR /app

# copy jar from the first stage
COPY --from=builder /app/target/*.jar /app/app.jar

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
```

After using this approach, I solved this problem. Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

This is working solution as I don't find anywhere this solution:

mvnw -version
**error:**
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be
non-empty

***Root Cause:***
maven public certificate is missing in java trust store

***Solutions:***

1. download - repo.maven.apache.org leaf certificate from https://repo.maven.apache.org and save it as repo_maven.cer file in base64 format
2. Install the repo_maven.cer into to cacerts (truststore)
   **keytool -import -keystore "...\openjdk-8u41\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -file "repo_maven.cer" -alias maven**

***Output:***
mvnw -version
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I just create another Spring project with Initializer and copy / paste `mvnw` and `mvnw.cmd` in the "old" project: after that it was found by Docker (version bump from `3.8.6` to `3.8.7` don't know if it was the problem).

Just edit `.mvn/maven-wrapper.prop` to be in part the with new version after that also.