# Build docker error: "/bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: not found"

Tags: docker, maven

I try to build a Maven project using dockerfile, but I got this error when I used command `docker build`:

> /bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: not found

I have tried this solution:
*[Unable to run './mvnw clean install' when building docker image based on "openjdk:8-jdk-alpine" for Spring Boot app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52748640/unable-to-run-mvnw-clean-install-when-building-docker-image-based-on-openjd/52748878)*

But I still got an error.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1 Build the Spring Project into a JAR file
FROM openjdk:8-slim as builder
RUN mkdir src
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN chmod 700 mvnw && ./mvnw clean install package  ==> An error on this line

# Stage 2 Run the JAR file from the previous build
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
COPY --from=builder /src/target /build
WORKDIR /build
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5001
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "tax-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: could you try like, "RUN chmod 700 mvnw && mvnw clean install package  ==>error on this line" without "./"

Comment: @JMadushan : i already try it, but got /bin/sh: 1: mvnw: not found

Comment: I guess you are not copying maven wrapper (mvnw) to the image. you could run "RUN ls" after the line "WORKDIR /src" just to inspect that.

Comment: @JMadushan : after i add run ls , i get the list of file as below, 
Compiler,
Dockerfile,
mvnw,
mvnw.cmd,
pom.xml,
src,
target, is this mean something? sorry i newbie in docker,

Comment: You may have a look at [Dockerfile : /bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74597445/dockerfile-bin-sh-1-mvnw-not-found-error/75234575#75234575) for workaround.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I was facing the same issue when building an image based on openjdk:14-alpine from a Windows 10 machine. The issue was that locally the `mvnw` script had Windows line endings (`\r\n` called CRLF).

I've tried calling the script with `/bin/sh mvnw` but I would still have problems. The first solution was to convert the line endings to Linux EOL (`\n` called "LF") from my IDE.

A better approach is to install `dos2unix` and run `dos2unix mvnw` just before calling the script. On Linux Slim (Debian) you may do `apt-get update && apt-get install dos2unix`.

You may also try `chmod +x mvnw` to make the script executable.

Comment: Can anyone provide me a pointer that where should I add the **apt-get update && apt-get install dos2unix** in the docker file. I did not able to fully understand the solution.

Comment: This question is about running `./mvnw` in a Linux container, for code written in Windows. You need to install the package and run it on the "mvnw" file before trying to execute it (e.g. line 6 in the OP's code).

Comment: `\r` and `\n` do not map cleanly to CR and LF.

Comment: See e.g. [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747722/what-is-the-difference-between-a-line-feed-and-a-carriage-return/12747850#comment129299456_12747850): *" \n is not a character. You will not find it in ASCII, ANSI, Latin-8, UTF-8 etc. It is a programming language-specific escape sequence, originating from the language C. And it NEVER means LF. It stands for the escape-sequence representing the platform's (OS) control character for new-line."*

Answer (score 15):

Try cleaning your mvnw file by removing spaces and CR characters from the file, using:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' mvnw
```

I was able to execute the mvn script inside the container after using this command.

Answer (score 4):

I used the following to fix the problem:

```
# clean up the file
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//' mvnw
# run with the SH path
RUN /bin/sh mvnw dependency:resolve
```

Answer (score 2):

> solution was to convert the line endings to Linux EOL (\n called "LF") from my IDE.

This is correct as stated in the posts by helvete and Uyric.

In Visual Studio Code I just opened the "mvnw" file and selected "LF" from the VSCode bottom-right status bar. Next, the docker build worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I had tested that can solve it:

1. use [dos2unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos), converting line endings after copying the mvnw file, like this:

   ```
    # syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

    FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy

    WORKDIR /app
    COPY .mvn/ .mvn
    COPY mvnw pom.xml ./

    # Converting the mvnw line endings during build (if you don’t change line endings of the mvnw file)
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix
    RUN dos2unix ./mvnw

    RUN ./mvnw dependency:resolve

    COPY src ./src

    CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
   ```
2. use a text editor (like [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)), open the mvnw file, and change line endings in the bottom right directly. It’s easier!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. If the file has a line ending of Windows format it will not be parsed as a Linux file. Therefore, it will result into not found file.

To solve it, install `sudo apt-get install dos2unix` and run `dos2unix mvnw`. This converts the file into a Linux line ending type, so it is recognized as a Linux file.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10,

**Step 1:** Download Dos2Unix from here:

https://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html#DOS2UNIX

[image]

**Step 2:** Unzip downloaded folder

[image]

**Step 3:** Copy unzipped folder

**Step 4:** Go to `C:\Users\myusername` ("myusername" is just an example here, you should write your username)

**Step 5:** Paste the folder.

**Step 6:** Open [system environment variable settings](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/114094235653-Setting-global-environment-variables-on-Windows):

[image]

**Step 7:** Copy your bin path or just this line : `C:\Users\myusername\dos2unix-7.4.2-win64\bin`  (change myusername with yours) and paste it into the new variable.

[image]

**Step 8:** **Done! just close and reopen command line or your IDE.**

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution! Every modern IDE has the option to change the line ending format.

[image: The print screen of the dam option]

Just select the whole code, and change it to the Mac OS format.

Solved.

~at least for me, it worked as a charm

Comment: No apt needed, just change it from the IDE itself.

Comment: Classic Mac OS? Why would you want to use that?

Answer (score 1):

install bash in your docker image.

#!/bin/bash

Comment: @petermortensen is just going through and making minuscule edits to everyone's post.. not sure what the game is... but ill take the point deduction. go away dude.. i got the point across.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bat file with the below script to convert `\r\n` to `\n`:

```
powershell -NoProfile -command "((Get-Content 'mvnw') -join \"`n\") + \"`n\" | Set-Content -NoNewline 'mvnw1'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to use Uyric and helvete's solution, then my Dockerfile work.

```sh
yum install dos2unix
dos2unix mvnw
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found that once we have the CRLF error, the mvnw file may be cached. So while we run the docker build again after the CRLF, it was replaced with CR. We should add `--no-cache` to make it take effect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Add `--no-cache` to what?

Comment: This worked for me. I ran `docker build . --no-cache` and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another "working" build-deploy dockerfile script like this.

```
FROM maven:3.8-openjdk-18 AS build
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM openjdk:18-alpine
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/projectName-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/app/projectName-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/app/projectName-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

You should change projectName with your jar file's name and prefer another maven version and jdk version.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same pb i just create another Spring project with Initialzr and copy / paste mvnw and mvnw.cmd in the "old" projet : after that it was found by Docker (version bump from 3.8.6 to 3.8.7 don't know if it was the pb).

Just edit .mvn/maven-wrapper.prop to be in part the with new version after that also.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to build their app with docker-compose on Windows, I the same error :

> exec: ".\mvnw": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

or

> /bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: not found

The solution that worked for me was to change the 1st line of the mvnw file from  `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`.