# Not able to execute mvnw command in Dockerfile [CLOSED/FIXED]

Tags: java, docker

I am new to Docker and i want to build my jar file in a container using
command `mvnw package` but i am getting
this error.
`ERROR [3/3] RUN ./mvnw package                                                                                 0.5s ------ > [3/3] RUN ./mvnw package: #7 0.448 /bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: not found ------ executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./mvnw package]: exit code: 127`

I have java version 8 installed from OpenJDK image.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN ./mvnw package

CMD ["java", "-jar", "./target/springjava.jar"]
```

and my directory is [Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7yof.png)

Using maven image it works as expected

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN mvn clean package

CMD ["java", "-jar", "./target/springjava.jar"]
```

SOLUTION : On windows system you have to "Convert the mvnm script file to Unix format by removing carriage return characters".

```
FROM openjdk:8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . . 

RUN sed -i 's/\r//' mvnw

RUN ./mvnw package

CMD ["java", "-jar", "./target/springjava.jar"]
```

Comment: Either the path to the executable is wrong or the image you use just does not have maven installed.

Comment: You might want to try giving yourself the permission to access the file with `chmod`. Aside from that, I am unsure about `COPY . .`. Try using the full target path instead, e.g. `COPY . /app` (assuming the `WORKDIR` is set to `/app`). If you're installing Maven via `apt-get`, you'd need to use `mvn` and not `./mvnw`.

Comment: @dan1st tried using chmod to give permission but gives mvnw does not exist. I used CMD ["ls", "-l"] to list all files and i can see mvnw
```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   70 Aug  4 13:01 Dockerfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  259 Aug  3 19:09 README.md
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 9399 Aug  3 19:09 mvnw
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5971 Aug  3 19:09 mvnw.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1834 Aug  3 19:09 pom.xml
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Aug  4 07:24 src
```

Comment: could you just package the jar from your IDE and copy it to your docker image when building instead?

Comment: Can you try changing `COPY . .` to `COPY . /app` and add `WORKDIR /app` right after the `COPY` command?

Comment: @dan1st tried that but not able to run mvnw command to build the jar, it has to be run from a bash env and I dont know how to do it.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X i want to build the jar inside the container and then run it. Issue is i am not able to use mvnw package command

Comment: What makes you think you'd need to run it from a bash env?

Comment: If you really insist on doing that, then you can just use a docker image provided by maven to build your jar inside the docker image. See [here](https://gauthier-cassany.com/posts/build-jar-inside-docker) and the relevant [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/maven/3.6.3-jdk-8/images/sha256-09c4bf58d7e7e31bdc1ab73ef10349b3a47c9a814e715e409034fb3293253ce2) from maven

Comment: @dan1st I ran the command `./mvnw package` from my local git bash it created the jar file.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Using maven:3.6.3-jdk-8 works fine. Thanks. But I have to build the jar with this command "./mvnw package".

Comment: @experimentunit1998X that was a mistake, i ran both ways just to see

Comment: could take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59214879/16034206

Comment: @experimentunit1998X yes it worked, thank you so much. I had to include this ``RUN sed -i 's/\r//' mvnw`` before running mvnw command